# Javascript: get values that contain in all arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

There are multiple arrays

1. `[1,2,3]`
2. `[2,3,4]`
3. `[2,4,5]`

Now I want to get the values that contain in all arrays. In this example it would be `[2]`. Is there an easy way to do this?

I tired https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438954/639035 however, if I try it with three arrays after each other, I get wrong results (4 would be included).

**Update**
Posted answer works, the error was in another part of my code

Comment: Post your non working code here in the question.

Comment: If your desired output is `[2]`, aren't you looking for the *non-*unique values? I.e.: the value that appears in every array.

Comment: Can you explain why 2 rather than 1?

Comment: Ahhh the error was in another part of the code.... not shure if I should delete it :/ Solution posted in the answer works!

Comment: Delete this question because was totally unclear.

Comment: Cannot delete it anymore (too many answers, comments) will accept @Mohammad Usman answer

Comment: @Stefan try again

Comment: Still no........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You may use:**

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [`Arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

**Example:**

```js
let a1 = [1, 2, 3];
let a2 = [2, 3, 4];
let a3 = [2, 4, 5];

let result = a1.filter(v => a2.includes(v) && a3.includes(v));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This solution is against what was stated in the questions title.

Comment: @Ele I assumed OP wants to filter values that exists in all arrays. At least this is what his expected output tells us.

Comment: @MohammadUsman, I think it's that, I edited the post and he approved with that change

Answer (score 0):

**This will work:**

```
let a = [1,2,3];
let b = [2,3,4];
let c = [2,4,5];

let result = a.reduce((total, elem) => {
    if((b.indexOf(elem) !== -1) && (c.indexOf(elem) !== -1)) {
        total.push(elem);
    }
    return total;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```